# ActionLink not behaving consistently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have two controllers, each with an action using the route attribute. On my view I use the @Html.ActionLink helper to render links to each of the actions. However, one of the actions fails to render the correct url.

Here is what I have so far:

**View**

```
<div class="actionRow row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRequest", "Modelling", new { @requestId = Model.RequestId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Details", "Business", new { @pRef = Model.PRef }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Modelling Controller**

```
public class ModellingController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("modelling/{requestId}")]
    public ActionResult EditRequest(int requestId)
    {
    }
}
```

**Business Controller**

```
public class BusinessController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("business/details-card/{pRef}")]
    public ActionResult Details(string pRef)
    {
    }
}
```

**Results**

In this fashion I get the following urls generated on the page:
http://localhost:8061/modelling/3211
http://localhost:8061/business/details?pRef=bds1234

The first link is correct, however I am expecting the second link to look like
http://localhost:8061/business/details-card/bds1234

**Further details**

If I alter the view to have the following mark-up then I do actually get the correct link generated, however it isn't styled - for obvious reasons. However, if I then try to add the class details they get appended to the link as querystring parameters.

**Altered View**

```
<div class="actionRow row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRequest", "Modelling", new { @requestId = Model.RequestId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Details", "Business", new { }, new { @pRef = Model.PRef })
    </div>
</div>
```

yields http://localhost:8061/business/details-card/bds1324

**Further Altered View**

```
<div class="actionRow row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRequest", "Modelling", new { @requestId = Model.RequestId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Details", "Business", new { @class = "btn btn-info" } new { @pRef = Model.PRef })
    </div>
</div>
```

yields http://localhost:8061/business/details-card/bds1234?class=btn btn-info

**More Information**

There are no other controllers and no other actions in the controllers, I have the map attribute routing correctly enabled in the route.config

Comment: I should add, this is happening in a view for the Modelling Controller if that makes any difference

Comment: It looks as though you have your params mixed up - htmlAttributes should be the last param, routeValues before: [ActionLink Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)

Comment: @Ric You should see that my original has the route and html values in the correct order. I only showed the option with them switched to highlight the fact is seemed to recognise the route correctly. This doesn't work as the styling isn't applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it helped to add:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

In RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

In View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRequest", "Modelling", new { @requestId = 1 }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Details", "Business", new { @pRef = "123" }, new {@class = ""})
```

Comment: I already have my route config looking like that, im starting to suspect the default route is picking this up in certain situations, but its not clear what those situations are

Comment: I ran your code and had to add routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes (); and it helped. I think that the order is important. I changed this your view - actionlink - added up

Comment: im marking this as the answer as it prompted me to find my own stupidity! When i copied your thinking and added literal values to the pRef parameter it worked - leading me to find an incorrect configuration in my AutoMapper rule populating my ViewModel. As a result Model.PRef was null when not expected. Unbelievable silent fail by the helper though